# UITextview font nil in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextview

We get font property nil but its already set in `storyboard`.
But if I can set `selectable` property true than and than we can get the font.

I tried to set `selectable = true` and its working but i did not want to set this property true.

In my app, I must have to set `selectable` property false for `UITextview`.

So is there any way, How to set font without using `selectable` property true. ?

Comment: why don't you try to get info about the font via the _attributes_ of the current text? it may be tricky if the format is not homogenous, but if you can rely on homogenous format, that is a quite straightforward thing to do so (see the [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview) Class Ref. for further info).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
textView.isSelectable = true
textView.font = UIFont(name: "yourFontName", size: 12)    // Change as required
textView.isSelectable = false.
```

Since the code with execute in one go, you'll get the font and `isSelectable` will be then set to `false`

Comment: We have to set font not get.
I edited my question.
Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Edited my answer